# JVM / ColdFusion "The system cannot find the file specified" LCK errors

Tags: coldfusion, jvm, jvm-arguments, jrun

I am a Coldfusion wiz, but my JVM error logs are filling up with the following types of errors.  Could someone shed some light on these for me and how to fix?  Much appreciated.  Searched for an hour everywhere and found no good answer or much of any reference.  That LCK part has me baffled, as the actual cfm file does indeed exist.

10/30 03:13:12 user RDSServlet: C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\stores.cfm.LCK (The system cannot find the file specified)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\stores.cfm.LCK (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:106)
 at coldfusion.rds.FileServlet$FileReadOperator.processCmd(FileServlet.java:156)
 at coldfusion.rds.FileServlet.processCmd(FileServlet.java:65)
 at coldfusion.rds.RdsServlet.doPost(RdsServlet.java:80)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:760)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:853)
 at coldfusion.rds.RdsFrontEndServlet.doPost(RdsFrontEndServlet.java:104)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:760)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:853)
 at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
 at jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)
 at jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)
 at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
 at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
 at jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
 at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$DownstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:320)
 at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
 at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$UpstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:266)
 at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like something related to Dreamweaver ... have a look at this http://www.houseoffusion.com/groups/cf-newbie/thread.cfm/threadid:277